# Combining pandas rows where for different columns different actions are required

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine certain rows but not with a common operation for all columns. I want the rows where pbheadid and wpadr are equal as in other row combined. Here the pickqty should be summed and the other columns should be copy pasted from the last entry or the highest pickdtm, but it is sorted so last entry will do.

I can presearch the indices and save them in a dictionary. And alter each row/column based on these indices. However, this is not that straight forward and fast. I think with pandas groupby something should be possible that is faster. Help would be appreciated. This is a piece of the data (note that pbheadid is similar but does alter in the larger dataset):

```
pbheadid    pbcarid     artid   wpadr   pickqty pickdtm

76079450    61838504    370944  523-370p    1   00:00:47
76079450    61838110    323775  523-372p    1   00:01:05
76079450    61838225    323775  523-372p    2   00:01:13
76079450    61838504    323775  523-372p    3   00:01:30
76079450    61838497    355475  523-373p    1   00:01:45
76079450    61838504    354194  523-377p    1   00:01:55
76079450    61838110    267204  523-376p    5   00:02:26
76079450    61838225    267204  523-376p    1   00:02:33
```

And this should be the outcome:

```
pbheadid    pbcarid     artid   wpadr   pickqty pickdtm
76079450    61838504    370944  523-370p    1   00:00:47
76079450    61838504    323775  523-372p    6   00:01:30
76079450    61838497    355475  523-373p    1   00:01:45
76079450    61838504    354194  523-377p    1   00:01:55
76079450    61838225    267204  523-376p    6   00:02:33
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do this:

```
In [21]: (df.groupby(['pbheadid','wpadr'])
   ....:    .agg({'pickqty':'sum', 'artid':'last', 'pbcarid':'last', 'pickdtm':'last'})
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....: )
Out[21]:
   pbheadid     wpadr   artid  pickqty   pbcarid   pickdtm
0  76079450  523-370p  370944        1  61838504  00:00:47
1  76079450  523-372p  323775        6  61838504  00:01:30
2  76079450  523-373p  355475        1  61838497  00:01:45
3  76079450  523-376p  267204        6  61838225  00:02:33
4  76079450  523-377p  354194        1  61838504  00:01:55
```